# A Question on the Application of Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f(z)$ be an entire function that satisfies $|f(z)|\leq 1+|z|, \ \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$. Show that $f(z)=az+b$ for fixed complex numbers $a$ and $b$.

My attempt:

Consider a circle, $\Gamma$, centered at the origin with radius $R$. Now, by Cauchy's Integral Formula:
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n \ \ \forall z,$$
where, $$f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \ dz.$$
Now suppose $\Gamma=\Gamma_R=Re^{it} \ \ t\in[0,2\pi]$. Then if $|z|=R$, we have:
$$\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\right|\leq\frac{1+R}{R^{n+1}}.$$
So, $$|f^{(n)}(0)|=\frac{n!}{2\pi}\left|\int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} \ dz\right|\leq\frac{n!}{2\pi}\frac{1+R}{R^{n+1}}2\pi R=\frac{n!(1+R)}{R^n}.$$
Now $|f^{(n)}(0)|\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$ for $n\geq 2$. But what is the answer (what is $a$ and $b$)?

Comment: Typo: it's not $f^n$; it's $f^{(n)}$.

Comment: That is true, I'll fix it now. Just out of curiosity, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have proved is  $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for $n \geq 2$ because $f^{(n)}(0)$ does not depend on $R$. From the power series expansion you get $f(z)=f(0)+f'(0)z$ so $a=f'(0), b=f(0)$.

Comment: Oh crap, how did I not see this. It's just the first two terms in the series as the remaining terms are all $0$ (which is what I proved).

Comment: Also, why do we take $|z|=R$?

Comment: The given inequality is useful for large values of $|z|$. So we use to over a large circle $\{|z|=R\}$ and let $R \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The title asks about an application of Liouville, but there's no Liouville in the proposed solution. If you want to do it by Liouville's  theorem consider $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}z.$$

Comment: Someone tell me what the problem with this is...

Comment: This is precisely Lioville's Theorem. If $|f(z)]\leq C, \ C>0$, is this not the proof that $f$ is constant if $f$ is a bounded entire function?

Comment: @Bell Huh? The fact that $|f(z)|\le 1+|z|$ shows that $g$ is a bounded entire function. So $g$ is constant. And $g(z)=c$ implies $f(z)=f(0)+cz$, as required.

Comment: Which is Lioville's theorem...

Comment: @Bell No, the statement usually known as Liouville's theorem is that a bounded entire  function is constant. Saying $||f(z)|\le 1+|z|$ does not say that $f$ is bounded, Saying that $f(z)=az+bz$ does not say that $f$ is constant. This is not Liouville's theorem, it's an application of Liouville's theorem. Which based on the title was what I thought you were interested in.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I have not down voted. Perhaps the wording of my title should be changed.

Answer (score -3):

Each pair $(a,b) \in \mathbb C^2$ with $|a|,|b| \le 1$ will do the job !

Comment: ??? The job is to show that if $|f(z)|\le1+|z|$ then $f(z)=a+bz$. Your  answer sounds as though you can show that if $f(z)=z$ then $f(z)=az+b$ for any $a,b$ with $|a|,|b|\le1$. Surely you don't mean  that...